# AddModelError for child objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a settings page on my site that uses these model classes:

```
public class NameVm
{
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
}

public class PasswordVm
{
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class AccountVm
{
    public NameVm Name { get; set; }
    public PasswordVm Password { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public override ActionResult Index()
    {
        var accountVm = AccountVmFromActiveUser();
        return View(accountVm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditName(NameVm vm)
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditPassword(PasswordVm vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (!ValidateUser(this.ActiveUser, vm.OldPassword))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("????",
                    "Existing password is incorrect.");
            }
            else
                UpdateUserPassword(vm);
        }

        var accountVm = AccountVmFromActiveUser();
        accountVm.Password = vm;
        return View(accountVm);
    }
}
```

In my `Account.cshtml` file I define two forms - one that submits to `EditName`, one that submits to `EditPassword`. It's a big file, so here is a small excerpt:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password.OldPassword)
@Html.ValidationFor(model => model.Password.OldPassword)
```

My question is: How do I get `ValidationFor` to display the error message I add in the `EditPassword` method? I tried using a key of `"Password.OldPassword"`, but this didn't work.

Alternatively, am I taking the wrong approach here? How should I handle having two forms on the same page?

Comment: What if you use the value of the "id" attribute of the input element that is rendered by the @Html.EditFor() as the key to .AddModelError? or are you?

Comment: Your bigger problem is that you create the elements for model type AccountVM, but your controller post expects PasswordVM - the values would never get there from the form because the input elements are named "Password.OldPassword" but the model binder looks for simply "OldPassword". You should change the EditPassword to receive the parameter of type AccountVM and then use the password property from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Partial Views.

1) in `Account.cshtml` separate the form that submits passord and put it in a partial view `_EditPassword.cshml` (usually I put the partial views in `Views\Shared` folder)

use

```
@Html.Partial("_EditPassword", @Model.Password)
```

to render the partial View in `Account.cshtml`

2) in the partial view `_EditPassword.cshtml` you can use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OldPassword)
@Html.ValidationFor(model => model.OldPassword)
```

and you should see validation errors